# How to access predefined Variable System.StageDisplayName in Release Pipe?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to install a windows service with the name of the stage variable.

To do so, i create a release pipeline that runs a  "Deploy Windows Service".
In the "Service Name" textbox i tried the following values with no success:

- $(System.StageDisplayName)
- ${{System.StageDisplayName}}

According to this documentation [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax), the one of them should had worked.

What am i missing?

*Update*:

yaml for the task:

```
steps:

- task: 
 MDSolutions.WindowsServiceManagerWindowsServiceManager.WindowsServiceManager.WindowsServiceManager@4
 displayName: 'Deploy Windows Service'
 inputs:
 DeploymentType: DeploymentGroup
 ServiceName: '$(System.StageDisplayName)'
 ArtifactPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_TestPipelines/WF_WSRV'
 StartService: false
 InstallService: true
 InstallationPath: 'd:\temp\testPipeLines\ConsoleApp1.exe'
```

Log:

```
2021-01-12T15:07:31.5340093Z ##[section]Starting: Release
2021-01-12T15:07:31.9679567Z ##[section]Starting: Initialize job
2021-01-12T15:07:31.9681931Z Agent name: 'someHost'
2021-01-12T15:07:31.9682581Z Agent machine name: 'someHost'
2021-01-12T15:07:31.9683002Z Current agent version: '2.179.0'
2021-01-12T15:07:31.9719710Z Agent running as: 'someHost$'
2021-01-12T15:07:31.9733457Z Prepare release directory.
2021-01-12T15:07:31.9745523Z ReleaseId=18, TeamProjectId=508ecdd3-89f6-4d7e-a21c-21537cff1fd3, ReleaseDefinitionName=New release pipeline
2021-01-12T15:07:31.9831990Z Release folder: C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a
2021-01-12T15:07:32.0008280Z Environment variables available are below.  Note that these environment variables can be referred to in the task (in the ReleaseDefinition) by replacing "_" with "." e.g. AGENT_NAME environment variable can be referenced using Agent.Name in the ReleaseDefinition: 
                [AGENT_DEPLOYMENTGROUPID] --> [79]
                [AGENT_DISABLELOGPLUGIN_TESTFILEPUBLISHERPLUGIN] --> [true]
                [AGENT_DISABLELOGPLUGIN_TESTRESULTLOGPLUGIN] --> [true]
                [AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY] --> [C:\azagent\A2]
                [AGENT_ID] --> [12]
                [AGENT_JOBNAME] --> [Release]
                [AGENT_MACHINENAME] --> [someHost]
                [AGENT_NAME] --> [someHost]
                [AGENT_OS] --> [Windows_NT]
                [AGENT_OSARCHITECTURE] --> [X64]
                [AGENT_RELEASEDIRECTORY] --> [C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a]
                [AGENT_RETAINDEFAULTENCODING] --> [false]
                [AGENT_ROOTDIRECTORY] --> [C:\azagent\A2\_work]
                [AGENT_SERVEROMDIRECTORY] --> [C:\azagent\A2\externals\vstsom]
                [AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY] --> [C:\azagent\A2\_work\_temp]
                [AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY] --> [C:\azagent\A2\_work\_tool]
                [AGENT_VERSION] --> [2.179.0]
                [AGENT_WORKFOLDER] --> [C:\azagent\A2\_work]
                [AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT] --> [VSTS_29caa32c-2a10-4a54-a782-fe32e17aa640_release_1_18_18_1]
                [BUILD_BUILDID] --> [228]
                [BUILD_BUILDNUMBER] --> [20210112.3]
                [BUILD_BUILDURI] --> [vstfs:///Build/Build/228]
                [BUILD_DEFINITIONID] --> [6]
                [BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME] --> [TestPipelines]
                [BUILD_PROJECTID] --> [508ecdd3-89f6-4d7e-a21c-21537cff1fd3]
                [BUILD_PROJECTNAME] --> [TestPipelines]
                [BUILD_REPOSITORY_ID] --> [3e1f9dd4-9753-4b35-b1b7-4698f840ea0b]
                [BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME] --> [TestPipelines]
                [BUILD_REPOSITORY_PROVIDER] --> [TfsGit]
                [BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR] --> [me]
                [BUILD_REQUESTEDFORID] --> [c19a3c62-d21c-6179-8fc5-b86c7cc1adda]
                [BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH] --> [refs/heads/master]
                [BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME] --> [master]
                [BUILD_SOURCEVERSION] --> [65538a246668cb53e8f1b56f8fa568ad29fe7a6b]
                [BUILD_TYPE] --> [Build]
                [GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT] --> [0]
                [MSDEPLOY_HTTP_USER_AGENT] --> [VSTS_29caa32c-2a10-4a54-a782-fe32e17aa640_release_1_18_18_1]
                [NODE] --> [whatever]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_BUILDID] --> [228]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_BUILDNUMBER] --> [20210112.3]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_BUILDURI] --> [vstfs:///Build/Build/228]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_DEFINITIONID] --> [6]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_DEFINITIONNAME] --> [TestPipelines]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_PROJECTID] --> [508ecdd3-89f6-4d7e-a21c-21537cff1fd3]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_PROJECTNAME] --> [TestPipelines]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_REPOSITORY_ID] --> [3e1f9dd4-9753-4b35-b1b7-4698f840ea0b]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_REPOSITORY_NAME] --> [TestPipelines]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_REPOSITORY_PROVIDER] --> [TfsGit]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_REQUESTEDFOR] --> [me]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_REQUESTEDFORID] --> [c19a3c62-d21c-6179-8fc5-b86c7cc1adda]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_SOURCEBRANCH] --> [refs/heads/master]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_SOURCEBRANCHNAME] --> [master]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_SOURCEVERSION] --> [65538a246668cb53e8f1b56f8fa568ad29fe7a6b]
                [RELEASE_ARTIFACTS__TESTPIPELINES_TYPE] --> [Build]
                [RELEASE_ATTEMPTNUMBER] --> [1]
                [RELEASE_DEFINITIONENVIRONMENTID] --> [1]
                [RELEASE_DEFINITIONID] --> [1]
                [RELEASE_DEFINITIONNAME] --> [New release pipeline]
                [RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFOR] --> [me]
                [RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL] --> [some email]
                [RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_REQUESTEDFORID] --> [c19a3c62-d21c-6179-8fc5-b86c7cc1adda]
                [RELEASE_DEPLOYMENT_STARTTIME] --> [2021-01-12 15:07:25Z]
                [RELEASE_DEPLOYMENTID] --> [27]
                [RELEASE_DEPLOYPHASEID] --> [27]
                [RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTID] --> [18]
                [RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTNAME] --> [Stage 1]
                [RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTS_STAGE_1_STATUS] --> [InProgress]
                [RELEASE_ENVIRONMENTURI] --> [vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Environment/18]
                [RELEASE_PRIMARYARTIFACTSOURCEALIAS] --> [_TestPipelines]
                [RELEASE_REASON] --> [Manual]
                [RELEASE_RELEASEDESCRIPTION] --> []
                [RELEASE_RELEASEID] --> [18]
                [RELEASE_RELEASENAME] --> [Release-18]
                [RELEASE_RELEASEURI] --> [vstfs:///ReleaseManagement/Release/18]
                [RELEASE_RELEASEWEBURL] --> [https://dev.azure.com/SomeOrg/508ecdd3-89f6-4d7e-a21c-21537cff1fd3/_release?releaseId=18&_a=release-summary]
                [RELEASE_REQUESTEDFOR] --> [me]
                [RELEASE_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL] --> [some email]
                [RELEASE_REQUESTEDFORID] --> [c19a3c62-d21c-6179-8fc5-b86c7cc1adda]
                [RELEASE_SKIPARTIFACTSDOWNLOAD] --> [False]
                [RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS] --> []
                [REQUESTEDFORID] --> [c19a3c62-d21c-6179-8fc5-b86c7cc1adda]
                [S1] --> [V1]
                [S1_1] --> [V1.1]
                [S2] --> [V2]
                [SERVICE_LOG] --> [Yahooo.log]
                [SYSTEM] --> [deployment]
                [SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY] --> [C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a]
                [SYSTEM_COLLECTIONID] --> [29caa32c-2a10-4a54-a782-fe32e17aa640]
                [SYSTEM_CULTURE] --> [en-US]
                [SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY] --> [C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a]
                [SYSTEM_ENABLEACCESSTOKEN] --> [False]
                [SYSTEM_HOSTTYPE] --> [deployment]
                [SYSTEM_JOBID] --> [876af16a-e99f-4cb5-8400-2b6d9e1f563f]
                [SYSTEM_JOBPARALLELISMTAG] --> [Private]
                [SYSTEM_PLANID] --> [a4218624-0ddd-418e-89e5-e0773133adcf]
                [SYSTEM_SERVERTYPE] --> [Hosted]
                [SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI] --> [https://dev.azure.com/SomeOrg/]
                [SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI] --> [https://dev.azure.com/SomeOrg/]
                [SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI] --> [https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/SomeOrg/]
                [SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT] --> [TestPipelines]
                [SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID] --> [508ecdd3-89f6-4d7e-a21c-21537cff1fd3]
                [SYSTEM_TIMELINEID] --> [a4218624-0ddd-418e-89e5-e0773133adcf]
                [SYSTEM_WORKFOLDER] --> [C:\azagent\A2\_work]
2021-01-12T15:07:32.2915884Z Creating artifacts directory: C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a
2021-01-12T15:07:32.2982021Z Created artifacts directory: C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a
2021-01-12T15:07:32.3055852Z Download all required tasks.
2021-01-12T15:07:32.7231433Z Checking job knob settings.
2021-01-12T15:07:32.7243979Z Finished checking job knob settings.
2021-01-12T15:07:32.7655197Z Start tracking orphan processes.
2021-01-12T15:07:32.7785905Z ##[section]Finishing: Initialize job
2021-01-12T15:07:32.8558573Z ##[section]Starting: Download artifact - _TestPipelines - WF_WSRV
2021-01-12T15:07:33.0121633Z ==============================================================================
2021-01-12T15:07:33.0123201Z Task         : Download pipeline artifact
2021-01-12T15:07:33.0124591Z Description  : Download a named artifact from a pipeline to a local path
2021-01-12T15:07:33.0125078Z Version      : 1.2.5
2021-01-12T15:07:33.0126070Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-01-12T15:07:33.0127980Z Help         : Download a named artifact from a pipeline to a local path
2021-01-12T15:07:33.0128621Z ==============================================================================
2021-01-12T15:07:34.4795690Z Download from the specified build: #228
2021-01-12T15:07:34.4799883Z Download artifact to: C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a/_TestPipelines/WF_WSRV
2021-01-12T15:07:36.1654076Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 6df03d2d-dbc3-489a-a45d-76f46e71632c
2021-01-12T15:07:37.3218435Z DedupManifestArtifactClient will correlate http requests with X-TFS-Session 6df03d2d-dbc3-489a-a45d-76f46e71632c
2021-01-12T15:07:37.3243608Z Minimatch patterns: [**]
2021-01-12T15:07:39.6332304Z Filtered 3 files from the Minimatch filters supplied.
2021-01-12T15:07:39.6678572Z Downloaded 0.0 MB out of 0.0 MB (0%).
2021-01-12T15:07:40.3239522Z Downloaded 0.0 MB out of 0.0 MB (100%).
2021-01-12T15:07:40.3259677Z 
2021-01-12T15:07:40.3262173Z Download statistics:
2021-01-12T15:07:40.3263971Z Total Content: 0.0 MB
2021-01-12T15:07:40.3266820Z Physical Content Downloaded: 0.0 MB
2021-01-12T15:07:40.3268581Z Compression Saved: 0.0 MB
2021-01-12T15:07:40.3269896Z Local Caching Saved: 0.0 MB
2021-01-12T15:07:40.3271064Z Chunks Downloaded: 3
2021-01-12T15:07:40.3272593Z Nodes Downloaded: 0
2021-01-12T15:07:40.3273340Z 
2021-01-12T15:07:40.3355756Z Download completed.
2021-01-12T15:07:41.1102884Z ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 2 events with X-TFS-Session 6df03d2d-dbc3-489a-a45d-76f46e71632c
2021-01-12T15:07:41.1109500Z Downloading artifact finished.
2021-01-12T15:07:41.1757354Z ##[section]Finishing: Download artifact - _TestPipelines - WF_WSRV
2021-01-12T15:07:41.1955160Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Windows Service
2021-01-12T15:07:41.6218704Z ==============================================================================
2021-01-12T15:07:41.6219747Z Task         : Windows Service Manager
2021-01-12T15:07:41.6220498Z Description  : Deploys a Windows Service to an Agent or a Deployment Group Target using WinRM.
2021-01-12T15:07:41.6221233Z Version      : 4.5.0
2021-01-12T15:07:41.6221694Z Author       : MDSolutions
2021-01-12T15:07:41.6222656Z Help         : [More Information](https://github.com/Dejulia489/WindowsServiceManager)
2021-01-12T15:07:41.6223515Z ==============================================================================
2021-01-12T15:07:43.2522920Z [someHost]: Attempting to locate [$(System.StageDisplayName)]
2021-01-12T15:07:43.9859710Z [someHost]: Identified [$(System.StageDisplayName)] installation directory [d:\temp\testPipeLines]
2021-01-12T15:07:43.9876695Z [someHost]: Copying [C:\azagent\A2\_work\r2\a\_TestPipelines\WF_WSRV] to [d:\temp\testPipeLines]
2021-01-12T15:07:44.0525647Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Windows Service
2021-01-12T15:07:44.0754875Z ##[section]Starting: Finalize Job
2021-01-12T15:07:44.0804419Z Cleaning up task key
2021-01-12T15:07:44.0806951Z Start cleaning up orphan processes.
2021-01-12T15:07:44.0887055Z ##[section]Finishing: Finalize Job
2021-01-12T15:07:44.1066969Z ##[section]Finishing: Release
```

Comment: Yes, i'm using Windows service Manager. I don't exactly understand what you say, i can say that the task runs below a Deploy service group created inside the stage.
I added the yaml and log file. I don't see where i can download the yaml for all stage or pipeline.

Comment: Looking at the log i found that that variable does not exists on my release pipe. Found other that looks suitable for getting the name of the stage, the Release.EnvironmentName. Using this one instead it works as wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `System.StageDisplayName` is not set on release pipeline as i expected, according to the log.

I used the variable `Release.EnvironmentName` instead.

Comment: This was driving me crazy for hours. Thanks.